PHP stuck sometimes, unpredictably, apache2 not frozen
PHP stuck sometimes[1], unpredictably, apache2 can and will still load backgrounds on a minute interval, even for pages that call na.site.loadContent()[1] and which never complete the AJAX call that supplies the HTML (and other code) for any given URL.
KUbuntu 22.04 OS is misbehaving.
I'm hoping I can find some help here.
I'm not even sure how to diagnose this problem myself.
root@parakeet:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# ls
access_compat.load  alias.load       authn_core.load  authz_core.load  authz_user.load  autoindex.load  deflate.load  dir.load  filter.load   mime.conf  mpm_event.conf.bak  mpm_prefork.conf  negotiation.conf  php8.1.conf  reqtimeout.conf  rewrite.load   setenvif.load       ssl.conf  status.conf
alias.conf          auth_basic.load  authn_file.load  authz_host.load  autoindex.conf   deflate.conf    dir.conf      env.load  headers.load  mime.load  mpm_event.load.bak  mpm_prefork.load  negotiation.load  php8.1.load  reqtimeout.load  setenvif.conf  socache_shmcb.load  ssl.load  status.load

i've taken a look at the relevant /var/log/apache2/error.log file, and there's nothing to be found there.
it's as if the 'TimeOut 10' line that i added to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf is ignored, and besides, my page should behave like it did before the failed upgrade[1] to kubuntu 24.04; load everything in under a second.
[1] after 'variety' started showing errors somewhere in March i think, i upgraded my OS to kubuntu 24.04, without realizing that the couchdb guys had yet to release a *.deb file for 24.04.
since the couchdb guys are taking their time, to put it mildly, i downgraded to 22.04, re-installed the backend components, and now i'm stuck with this page-freezing issue. :(

Based on the info given here there is nothing to help you with. Please explain in detail what each of these items means with examples and error messages. PHP stuck sometimes, what does this mean? apache2 not frozen what does this mean?

i've edited my question.
and sorry for the overhead.

How is PHP being executed? Using fpm? Using Apache's module? What do the logs say when it hangs? Have you tried using verbose or debug logging for whichever component executes PHP?

PHP is executed as an apache2 module.
how would i set the debug logging to verbose or debug?
and how would i prevent staring at logs for days? ;)

Unfortunately you'll need to provide even more details I think. First off you should check what logs say (the app's log, if any, JS logs, if any, and Apache logs, starting with /var/log/apache2/error.log, or the error log defined in the virtual host's definition).

The only follow up question to your current explanation of the problem would be, since it appears as though you think AJAX requests are not completing: is the backend hosted on the same machine? Cause otherwise you should first check that the backend is responding correctly to the requests (tools like Insomnia / Postman are useful to debug HTTP requests), otherwise we'd be wasting useful time debugging the Ubuntu machine while the problem is actualy on the backend.

that rig was state-of-the-art in 2023, and provides me with a desktop, server, database server and all other backend functionality rolled into 1 kubuntu machine.

i've got the entire back-end, front-end producing HTML and related browser languages, and my desktop functionality on 1 machine running Kubuntu 22.04 alright.

and i could not find anything in the logs.

oh wait, i've yet to check the nginx logs! :D
i'll get back to this thread after the investigation. ;)

*/1 * * * * service apache2 restart && service nginx restart

added to 'crontab -e' on the commandline, seems to do the trick for me :)
i also raised the apache2 and nginx concurrent connections option (an int).
